# How to extract specific oracle version number from output file

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract Oracle version number from a text file.
my Text file data:-

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production 
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production 
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
Done processing file
```

so what i want here is just oracle major version (ex:- 11.2.0.2.0 - > 11)

I have working code but want to know any other best approach for this or any RegEx.

```
       EZFileReader reader = new EZFileReader( output_file );
       if ( reader.hasMoreLines() )
       {
          String version_line = reader.readNextLine().trim();
          if ( version_line != null )
          {
             String[] release = version_line.split(" ");
             if ( release.length > 0 )
             {
                String[] version = release[6].split("\\.");
                if ( version[0] != null )
                {
                   version_value = Integer.parseInt(version[0]);
                }
             }
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+)(?:\\.\\d+){4}" );

EZFileReader reader = new EZFileReader( output_file );
Integer version = null;
while( reader.hasMoreLines() )
{
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher( reader.readNextLine() );
  if ( m.find() )
  {
    version = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex:

> (\d+).(\d.)+\d

The first found group is a version number.

Below is code example:

```
   EZFileReader reader = new EZFileReader( output_file );
   if ( reader.hasMoreLines() )
   {
      String version_line = reader.readNextLine();
      if ( version_line != null )
      {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+\\.)+\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(version_line);

        if(matcher.find()) {
            version_value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: The regular expression needs `\\ ` as escape characters within the string. `reader.readNextLine()` should not be `null` if `reader.hasMoreLines()` and if it is then `.trim()` will cause it to error before you get to the check. Apart from that its almost a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: You still have `\.` in the regular expression.

Comment: It should be fine now.